# Vagrant suspending automatically on Mac OS

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I got Vagrant installed and I am using a provision script provided by Vaprobash.

I havent changed a bit of that script except for the ip, which runs fine.

The problem is that Vagrant stops the box without any notice and with no apparent reason.

My suspicious go toward the battery. Mac can go to 2% of battery without auto suspending, could the box be watching that and suspending due to low battery?

Has anyone else beeing through that?

Comment: I have experienced the same thing using Ubuntu 12.04 as a guest. I'd guess that it's a guest OS thing, not Vagrant itself. I found this http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/disabling-battery-in-ubuntu-vms.html showing how to disable power management in Ubuntu, but I cannot find the mentioned `upowerd`. still, I think it's Ubuntu who decides to suspend the VM. Worth checking system logs...

Comment: That was it. I disabled the power management and it stopped suspenging my vms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so as in my comment above, I suspected Ubuntu's power management for shutting down the machine rather than Vagrant. As you probably already know, you can set the action for when battery is critically low to 'nothing' (as found in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60998/273293)):

```
gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/gnome-power-manager/actions/critical_battery       nothing
```

Also, [here](http://blog.michaelkelly.org/2010_12_01_archive.html) I have found the same hint.

Additionally, you can play with other options if you like (found [here](http://guvnr.com/pc/gconf-editor-power-management/)):

```
/apps/gnome-power-manager/general/use_time_for_policy (false)
/apps/gnome-power-manager/thresholds/percentage_low (12)
/apps/gnome-power-manager/thresholds/percentage_critical (8)
/apps/gnome-power-manager/thresholds/percentage_action (5)
/apps/gnome-power-manager/actions/critical_battery (hibernate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer!

Comment: I'm using ubuntu server and don't have gnome installed (and thus no gconftool-2).  Is there another solution?  Also, it looks like there may be an issue with VirtualBox: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2691 and https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12441

Comment: @MattBriançon: hm... in general, googling is a useful skill in such cases ;) From what I found, here are a few options: 1. there is a tool called TLP (http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/how-to-improve-laptop-power-management.html) 2. you can tried this thread on AskUbuntu: http://serverfault.com/a/405387 3. you might find some useful info in Ubuntu Wiki as well (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower)

Comment: @piotr.d I actually did quite a bit of Googling but didn't find the ServerFault question so I'll give that a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who is running a headless vagrant box and looking for a way to prevent the guest from automatically suspending itself on low-battery, the following worked for me:

within your *Vagrantfile*:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--acpi", "off"]
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add, in 4.3.30 versions of VirtualBox you can now disable this behavior:

`VBoxManage setextradata global "VBoxInternal2/SavestateOnBatteryLow" 0`

Comment: From the VirtualBox manual: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#hostpowertweaks